# Ruby: trouble with batch variable assignment

Tags: ruby, loops, batch-processing

Yesterday, I started making a chess program and, trying to save 60-odd lines, decided to try my hand at batch variable assignment. That is, assigning variables through loops. I can't seem to join `spot_def_letters[i]` with `o_s` in the correct fashion, though. (`$board` is scoped for later use)

My code:

```
spot_def_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
8.times do
    i = 0
    o = 1
    8.times do
        o_s = o.to_s
        spot_def_letters[i] + o_s = "  "
        o += 1
    end
end
$board = """
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a8}|#{b8}|#{c8}|#{d8}|#{e8}|#{f8}|#{g8}|#{h8}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a7}|#{b7}|#{c7}|#{d7}|#{e7}|#{f7}|#{g7}|#{h7}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a6}|#{b6}|#{c6}|#{d6}|#{e6}|#{f6}|#{g6}|#{h6}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a5}|#{b5}|#{c5}|#{d5}|#{e5}|#{f5}|#{g5}|#{h5}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a4}|#{b4}|#{c4}|#{d4}|#{e4}|#{f4}|#{g4}|#{h4}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a3}|#{b3}|#{c3}|#{d3}|#{e3}|#{f3}|#{g3}|#{h3}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a2}|#{b2}|#{c2}|#{d2}|#{e2}|#{f2}|#{g2}|#{h2}
  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
#{a1}|#{b1}|#{c1}|#{d1}|#{e1}|#{f1}|#{g1}|#{h1}
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of indexing into string arrays and using a bunch of sneaky, bad-looking code, I decided to use a 64-value array (`spots = Array.new(64, " ")`) and `puts` those values.

Comment: @steenslag I'm aware of that. It's an early version so GUI isn't my main concern